# How to close a specific form in my project if it's once appeared

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication, formclosing

In my project , the first form is the **Login form** and it appears only one time for the user when he attempt to login the system .. If the login is successful then a **main form** of the system appears and login form hides , if login attempt is failed then the user may try another time and so on ..
The problem is when the user in the **main form** want to close the program using the X button the message of **Login form** of **FormClosing event** appears it logout in the case of user pressed Yes ,but when the user press NO the program do not close but it returns to **login form which is hidden** 
The codes for **FormClosing event** in **Login Form** are:

```
 private void LoginFrm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult logoutResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to logout?","Logout",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (logoutResult == DialogResult.No)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
            else
            {

                e.Cancel = false;
            }
        }
```

Now the same **FormClosing event** is happening for both **Login form and main form** how to make the program do nothing in case of the user pressed **NO** in logout messageBox and stay on its current situation and once the user login to system the **Login form** closes not hide .. regards

Comment: try :`e.Cancel = true;
        base.LoginFrm_FormClosing(e);`

Comment: @Vicky the compiler says Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' does not contain a definition for 'LoginFrm_FormClosing' C:\Users\Coder\Desktop\9\Phamacy Management System\Phamacy Management System\Form1.cs 73 22 Phamacy Management System

Comment: Why do you have *LoginFrm_FormClosing* event? It is not needed! When the user enters the correct password (i.e in a textbox) you just hide the login form. In the *logout messageBox* you close everything or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to show the *messageBox* on *LoginFrm_FormClosing* when everything is closing:

```
private void LoginFrm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        //Add this lines, your login form is hidden
        if (this.Visible == false)
        {
            return;
        }            

        DialogResult logoutResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to logout?","Logout",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (logoutResult == DialogResult.No)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {

            e.Cancel = false; //<- you dont need this
        }
    }
```

And in *MainForm*:

```
//Add this line
Boolean isClosed = false; //<--

private void MainFrm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        //Add this
        if(isClosed == true){
            return;
        }

        DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to exit?"); 

        if (res == DialogResult.OK) {
            try {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from empLogin where empId=" + deleteById + "", cn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //Add this line
                isClosed = true; //<--

                Application.Exit();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex) {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally { cn.Close(); } 
        }

    }
```

Comment: yes sir your answer did what I need but there is one problem and that is the message box appears twice .. these are the codes for FormClosing event of MainFrm :
private void MainFrm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to exit?");
 if (res == DialogResult.OK)
 {
 try{   
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from empLogin where empId=" + deleteById + "", cn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Application.Exit();
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
cn.Close();
}}}

Comment: @Tima'aTamim I see the problem! I forgot to write the code for *MainFrm*. See edited answer.

Comment: Thank you sir You have made my day this code worked with me successfully and finally I got what I've wanted .. I also made a small change in my code with the dialog box buttons I've used YesNo buttons instead of OK with this codes for else block (when user press no to not logout from the system) 
else
            {
                isClosed = false;
                e.Cancel = true;
            }

Answer (score 0):

Try this blow code by adding base.OnFormClosing(e); at top of your method

```
private void LoginFrm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnFormClosing(e);

        DialogResult logoutResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to logout?","Logout",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (logoutResult == DialogResult.No)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else
        {

            e.Cancel = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a better solution for showing login form.

In the Main function of your project show your login form, then in login form check user then set the `DialogResult` to OK and close the login form. If the login form returns and the DialogResult is OK show the Main form.

```
static void Main()
{
    var frm = new frmLogin().ShowDialog();

    if (frm == DialogResult.OK)
        Application.Run(new frmMain());
}
```

In this way the login form is closed before main form.

If you want a Logout function, you can show login form again and use DialogResult again. In your main form use this function:

```
private void Logout()
{
    var frm = new frmLogin().ShowDialog();

    // if new user is not identified.
    if (frm == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        // Close the main form
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain more , if I use this method in my program it must be written in which piece ..

Comment: write it in the program.cs in Main function